# Custom augmentation of serialization/deserialization of types that have class annotation

Tags: json, jackson

I'd like to have a bunch of classes that structures something like this:

```
@Special("SpecialThing")
data class MyThing(
    val myVal: String
)
```

The serialized format of this specific instance is this would be:

```json
{
  "special": "SpecialThing",
  "params": {
    "myVal": "myValValue"
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to serialize to/from these kinds of annotated types.

A few of the things I was hoping to do:

1. Keep Jackson annotations out of these classes themselves (maybe using [mixins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations)?). I'd to keep the Jackson specific serialization separate from these types.
2. Avoid putting the `"SpecialThing"` as a field/property
3. Deserialize into the correct type by use of the `"special"` value

I might not be able to accomplish all of these at once, but I'm having difficulty finding the right pieces of Jackson to use to accomplish my goal. There are a few built-ins which do close to what I want (like [`JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html))

I could maybe use `@JsonTypeInfo` and polymorphic inheritance in some way, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner and more direct approach.

How do I handle serialization/deserialization of these kinds of types that need "wrapping"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do it because you have a your own fancy annotation that jackson just doesn't care about, but you could do the other stuff with `@JsonWrapped` and mixin.

You will need to [write a custom JSON Serializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) to handle your annotation
which is really easy.

Comment: At least when I looked at the custom serializers/deserializers, most of them seem to be type-based when I would like them to use my annotation for serialization and the data to deserialize (some registration may be necessary for the deserializable types). I was hoping I could write one serializer and one deserializer to handle all of my types.

Comment: you can use `reflection` to find all classes with you annotation on the classpath and register them all at boot time or you can register `Object` for deserialization. Then, look at each object on the fly: if it has your annotation, apply your logic. Otherwise delegate to the original deserializer